# What's the difference between outline and ring in tailwind

Tags: css, tailwind-css

Tailwindcss supports both outline utility and ring.
While I understand that ring is implemented using shadows, I'm not sure what's the use case to use each of them.

Do you have an example when to use what and why? Is one of them more suitable for focus styles? Why?

Answer (score 11):

Both of these answers here are not quite correct.

You can change the width, color, offset, and opacity using both `ring` and `outline`.  The difference between the two is that `ring` uses the CSS box-shadow property, and `outline` uses the CSS outline property.

In the past, the main reason people preferred `box-shadow` was because `outline` wouldn't honor an element's border radius, but now it does.

Box shadow does offer more customization, but it is specifically via blur and the ability to support multiple colors -- not width, opacity, or a single color like the other answers suggest.

For most use cases, it doesn't matter which one you choose.

Comment: Thanks for your answer: ` The difference between the two is that ring uses the CSS box-shadow property, and outline uses the CSS outline property.` ---> more detail on the signifance of the difference between box-shadow vs outline would be well regarded.

Comment: There is also the difference that with ring-offset the space between ring and the element can't be transparent, hence the ring-offset-color utility to match with background, while with outline the space between is transparent.

Answer (score 7):

By the question, i assume you know the general use case of both `outline` and `ring`.
In a gist it can be used interchangeably, but `ring` is used when you want more customization and `outline` is used to produce simple effect.

To explain further,

**1. `outline`**

> It can be applied to create a decorative effect, highlight a particular element, or serve as a focus indicator for keyboard navigation.

**2. `ring`**

> It provides more customising choices, like `size`, `colour`, and `opacity` may all be changed using the several iterations of the `ring` utility class. It can be used to highlight a button or input field in a circle when it is the focus or to create a border-like effect around an element.

In summary, `ring` is used to create a customisable ring around an element,  `outline` is often used to create a solid or dashed outline around an element. Use `ring` when you require additional customization choices or want to create a circular highlight effect, and use `outline` when you want a simpler, more basic effect.

Answer (score 1):

The main difference is that ring allows you to outline an element with different widths where outline allows you to do it with different styles.
See these two pages from the tailwind docs :

https://tailwindcss.com/docs/ring-width 
https://tailwindcss.com/docs/outline-style